# Royden 4th Ed., Chapter 2, Proposition 8

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Recall: 
$$
m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(I_k)\,:\,E\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right\}
$$
where 
$$
I_k = \text{ an open, bounded interval on }\mathbb{R}\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\ell(I_k)=\text{ the length of }I_k
$$

Here is the text of the proof as published:

$\textbf{Proposition 8}\,\,\textit{ Every interval is measurable.}$

$\textbf{Proof}\,\,$ As we observed above, the measurable sets are a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore to show that every interval is measurable it suffices to show that every interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ is measurable (see Problem 11). Consider such an interval. Let $A$ be any set. We assume that $a$ does not belong to $A$. Otherwise, replace $A$ by $A\sim\{a\}$, leaving the outer measure unchanged. We must show that 
$$
m^*(A_1)+m^*(A_2)\le m^*(A)
$$
where
$$
A_1=A\cap (-\infty,a)\,\,\text{and}\,\,A_2=A\cap (a,\infty).\qquad(5)
$$
By the definition of $m^*(A)$ as an infimum, to verify (5) it is necessary and sufficient to show that for any countable collection $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of open, bounded intervals that covers $A$,
$$
m^*(A_1)+m^*(A_2)\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(I_k).\qquad(6)
$$
Indeed, for such a covering, for each index $k$, define
$$
I'_k=I_k\cap(-\infty,a)\,\,\text{and}\,\,I''_k=I_k\cap (a,\infty).
$$
Then $I'_k$ and $I''_k$ are intervals and 
$$
\ell(I_k)=\ell(I'_k)+\ell(I''_k).
$$
Since $\{I'_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and $\{I''_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ are countable collections of open, bounded intervals that cover $A_1$ and $A_2$, respectively, by the definition of outer measure,
$$
m^*(A_1)\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I'_k)\,\,\text{and}\,\,m^*(A_2)\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I''_k).
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
m^*(A_1)+m^*(A_2)&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I'_k) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I''_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty [\ell(I'_k)+\ell(I''_k)]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k).
\end{align*}
$$
Thus (6) holds and the proof is complete.

---

Overall, this proof is very clear and makes sense. I am having a problem with one of the assumptions in the beginning of the proof: $E$ is a measurable set if for $every$ set $A$ we have
$$
m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^C),
$$
but this proof seems to ignore all sets containing $\{a\}$. Is this a flaw in the proof? I am not even sure why ignoring $\{a\}$ is necessary. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: A single pointy has measure $0$, so no issues there.

Comment: I understand that the outer measure of $A$ and $A\sim\{a\}$ are the same. But why is it even necessary to remove $a$ in the first place?

Comment: Open covers and stuff... just to ensure that you have an open interval. Makes the proof easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing $a$ allows you to use $(-\infty,a)$ instead of $(-\infty,a]$ in $(5)$. This in turn allows the $I_k'$ to cover $A_1$.

Removing $a$ is not an issue because, as the book says, $m^*(A\cap(-\infty,a])=m^*(A\cap(-\infty,a))$.

Comment: That is true. If $a\in A_1$, then none of $I'_k$ would be able to cover and hence $A_1\not\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I'_k$. So we could use intervals of the form $[a,\infty)$ and throw out the assumption, but it complicates the proof a bit, right?

Comment: Yes. To use the definition of the outer measure, you need a cover by open invervals.

Comment: Ah. So, actually, we have to proceed in the manner of the text. We have to have those open bounded covers otherwise the outer measure definition can't apply. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome.